# Checking where MC are placed

Tags: actionscript-3

For fun (and to learn) I am creating a random terrain generator in AS3. What I am having a problem with is trying to find out what type of tile (grass, stone, etc) is where. I need to know what tile is where to be able to say things like: if blank tile above and stone below add grass tile.

Currently I only have a while loop going through and adding the tiles and a invisible MC (objectCheck) going through the terrain, I was planning to use this objectCheck to check the terrain. but how would I make this while loop also check what tiles its on and tiles above and below?  Hope this is clear, I lack explaining abilities!

```
    function terrainChecker(){

        if(terrainCheckX < 200){
            while(terrainCheckY > 0){
                terrainCheckY -= blockSize;
                createTerrain();
                objectTypeChecker();
            }

        terrainCheckX += blockSize;
        terrainCheckY = depth;

        terrainChecker();

        }

    }
    function objectTypeChecker(){
        objectCheck.x = terrainCheckX;
        objectCheck.y = terrainCheckY;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea is to keep a clear model of your tiles and build a separate view layer to render it.

Example:

```
interface Tile {
    function get typeID():String;
}
class Water implements Tile {
    public function get typeID():String {
         return TYPE;
    }
    static public const TYPE:String = "water";
}
class Sand implements Tile {
    public function get typeID():String {
         return TYPE;
    }
    static public const TYPE:String = "sand";
}
```

Now a map looks like this (this is hardcoded, but you could just as well generate it):

```
var map:Array = [
    [new Water, new Sand, new Sand, new Water],
    [new Water, new Sand, new Sand, new Water],
    [new Water, new Sand, new Sand, new Water],
    [new Sand, new Sand, new Water, new Water]
]
```

And it could be rendered as:

```
var colors:Object = { water: 0x0000FF, sand: 0xFFFF00 };
const size:Number = 20;
for (var y:int = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
    var row:Array = map[y];
    for (var x:int = 0; x < row.length; x++) {
        beginFill(colors[Tile(row[x]).typeID]);
        drawRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
    }
}
```

Of course this is very simplified, but it should give you an idea.

And if you want to check which kind of tile is at which position, you can simply look in the map.